# css relative div height auto between two div

Tags: css, height

I try to have horizontal div to fill all the empty space of a container.

I didn't succeed to make the middle div (`.element-description`) to fill all empty gap (like in height: auto). (all other div have a defined height)
I tried with `display:table`, it near works but create some display bug in IE9.
I tried with css calc but it's not cross browser and it didn't solved all the problem.

I really don't know what to do. Maybe it's impossible in css?

css:

```
.element{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background: grey;
}
.element-back {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.title {
  position: relative;    
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.element-title-separator {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.element-image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 14.5%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.element-image img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -30%;
}
.element-description {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.element-description > div{
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.element.blog .element-description > div > div{
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    height:100%;
}
.element-read-more {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 40px;
}
.element-informations {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 40px; 
}
```

[fiddle without table](http://jsfiddle.net/UuFSg/260/)

[fiddle with display table](http://jsfiddle.net/UuFSg/252/)

hope that someone can help me...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You want all the divs to be 100% in width?

Comment: It's about one div in the middle. it will fill all the empty space (.element-description div). Actually with height auto it fill more than the empty space...

Comment: Are the top and bottom divs of a known height?

Comment: Bottom yes, but top it's in percent and px, so that's why I don't know how to do it... So the top is responsive and the middle text also. Not the bottom.

Comment: this should work for you the change the heights as required http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/9DLeg/

Comment: thank you for your help but it can't work like this... It's more complicated than this... The main div `.element`have a fixed height. My aim is to have a height for `.element-description`that fill automaticaly vertical gap. because all other div have a defined height. If this `.element-description` div have a lot's of amout of text, the text inside it will not affect the height of the div... That's my major problem. This fiddle have the correct behaviour but create some problems in IE and in some browser : http://jsfiddle.net/UuFSg/252/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to set position: absolute to the .element? Can't you set it to relative and use height: auto?
Is this what you're trying?

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/UuFSg/262/

```
.element{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  background: grey;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Position must be absolute. But with relative it didn't solve the problem. My element have a fixed height, I want that the .elemennt-description div fill empty space. I need to hide text that "overflow" and avoid to push div under...

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking for. The .element-description already fills the empty space and the overflown text is hidden. It was like that in your first solution.

Comment: The .element description push .element-informations and .element-read-more out of the .element main div. I want a result like this (without table because it's not working in IE9, and without css calc) :http://jsfiddle.net/UuFSg/252/

Answer (score 0):

The fixed value here must be the header and footer **height**, and you need to set the top and bottom of your content section whit the same value of footer and header height plus the value of the border-width here (100px + 5px).
I hope it help

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */
    background:gray;

    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    color:#666;
}

h1 { 
    font:1.5em georgia,serif; 
    margin:0.5em 0;
}

h2 {
    font:1.25em georgia,serif; 
    margin:0 0 0.5em;
}

h1, h2, a {
    color:orange;
}

p { 
    line-height:1.5; 
    margin:0 0 1em;
}

.box{
    border: 5px solid green;

}

#container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 60%;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: none;
    bor
}

/** Test html classic page */
#header{
    display:block;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
#content{
    position: absolute;

    /** The border over lap so 5px must be add*/
    top: 105px; bottom: 105px;
    right: 0; left: 0;
}
#footer{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 100px;
    right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```